# How to get Eclipse CDT working with WxWidgets under windows?

Tags: wxwidgets, eclipse-cdt

- wxWidgets-3.1.3
- Eclipse IDE 4.14.0
- Eclipse CDT 9.10.0.2019x (the latest packages as of 2/2/2020)
- MinGW compiler, installed via MSYS2
- Windows 10 Pro

I have been using Eclipse for years for PHP, Python, JavaScript, and lua.  I am, however, new to C++ and Eclipse CDT.  I've got a reasonable enough grip on C++ syntax and convention that I'm ready to move on to the reason I came to C++, which is GUI.  At first I tried Code::Blocks, which seemed simpler (I like wizards!), but I really would prefer an IDE with git integration, and I realised C::B didn't have that before I managed to get compilation working.  So, back to Eclipse.

So far, I have done the following:

- added the MinGW compiler path to %PATH%
- successfully compiled wxWidgets 3.1.3 using SHARED=0 UNICODE=1 MONOLITHIC=0 BUILD=release, these changes made in %WXDIR%\build\msw\config.gcc.  The various tutorials I have found wildly disagree on these parameters, but the various responses to people with my problem here and on other forums have all been generally in agreement on them, and with the exception of BUILD, they're the defaults.  So.
- successfully compiled a test program from samples/minimal.  The resulting executable runs without needing any other DLLs in the same directory.

Unfortunately, this is where I'm stuck.  There are plenty of tutorials and forum posts out there, but I run into one or more of the following problems:

- Not newbie accessible. "Add a link to your wxWidgets directory" but okay, how do I do that, and do you mean the main %WXDIR% code directory or %WXDIR%\lib or what?
- Don't work.  "Just File->Import->File System->%WXDIR%" and nope.  Did, in fact, get rid of the "not resolved" for SOME references in code pasted from "minimal.cpp", but not all.
- Explicitly refer to versions of the IDE or Code from, oh, say, ten years ago, and/or contain instructions that cannot be followed in the current version.

Alternately, I would take a recommendation for another GUI toolkit that has accessible instructions for getting the current version of itself working with the current version of Eclipse.

Comment: are you trying to create a new executable? or you want to set it up to try the minimal sample? Also - maybe wxPython will be easier for you, since you have a scripting experience?

Comment: anyway if you want to use C++ wxWidgets mainline you will need to describe what you did exactly and what problem(s) you encountered.

Comment: I'm trying to create a new executable using the minimal sample's code, through  Eclipse instead of the command line, figuring that once I have configured Eclipse to do that, I will be able to develop my own app with WxWidgets.  

What I've done consists of successfully compiling wxWidgets (and minimal.cpp) as described. I do not know what to do next, and every tutorial I find either contains vague instructions where it tells me what to do on a high level but not how to actually do it, or the instructions cannot be followed (missing options) in current version.

Comment: The one instruction I found that I was actually able to follow is described above under  "Don't work."  The problem is that Eclipse cannot resolve WxWidgets, and I don't know how to tell it how to do so.

Comment: WxPython looks DELICIOUS-- I did not know that was a thing!  I have played with a considerable less elegant gui toolkit, but I also need to be able to compile my program as a binary-- partly so that the user doesn't have to install python, and mostly because I don't want them to be able to tinker with the code in what is going to be a multiplayer game.  Oh, if I could do this project in Python I would be a very happy man; as a scripter I have been spoiled by Duck Typing, and Python is just wonderful in general.  But I need code obfuscation and easy distribution.

Comment: my understanding is that you can develop in {wx}Python and then create a binary using some specific python tool, whcih will just pack everything up in one binary and yu will be able to distribute it. Now in terms of using Eclipse with C++ and wxWidgets - I presume you have installed a latest version of it? I don't work with Eclipse and wxWIdgets - I'm using MSVC, Anjuta and Xcode.

Comment: And I am interfacing with the Git thru the GitHub client on Windows and the Terminal on *nix/OSX. So what you want to do is to start with the Empty project and then modify the include and Link properties of it. Check the forums.wxwidgets.org - I believe there were postings about Eclipse + wx there.

Comment: See, the problem is that things like "modify the include and link properties" are things that I don't know how to do.  That is is the exact kind of instruction I was referring to when I said "what to do but not how to do it."  And no, I have found no postings there that are for Windows... well, one talks about XP but it's not usuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll show how to compile the wxWidgets minimal sample with MinGW and eclipse.  First of all, I highly recommend that you build both a debug and a release version of the wxWidgets library.  These directions will assume that is the case. I'm not an expert with eclipse, so I can't guarantee these are the best directions.  These directions do work for me, but corrections and improvements are welcome.

There are many, many steps here.  But if you get a working project with the minimal sample, you can copy the project and change the code files to use it for further projects.

Before we do anything else, define the `WXWIN` environment variable in eclipse if it not already defined.  From the menu select Window->Preferences->C/C++->Build->Environment, and the press the add button to add the variable.

[image]

The easiest way to build the minimal sample that comes with the library is with the command line. To do this, simply change to the WXWIN\samples\minimal folder and enter the exact same command you used to build the library.  Since the command given above was `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=0 UNICODE=1 MONOLITHIC=0 BUILD=release`, this will result if the following commands being executed in the shell:

```
windres --use-temp-file -i../../samples/sample.rc -ogcc_mswu\minimal_sample_rc.o    --define __WXMSW__   --define NDEBUG    --define _UNICODE --include-dir .\..\..\lib\gcc_lib\mswu --include-dir ./../../include  --include-dir .  --include-dir ./../../samples --define NOPCH
g++ -c -o gcc_mswu\minimal_minimal.o  -O2 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__   -DNDEBUG    -D_UNICODE -I.\..\..\lib\gcc_lib\mswu -I.\..\..\include  -W -Wall -I.  -I.\..\..\samples -DNOPCH   -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy   -MTgcc_mswu\minimal_minimal.o -MFgcc_mswu\minimal_minimal.o.d -MD -MP minimal.cpp
g++ -o gcc_mswu\minimal.exe @gcc_mswu\minimal.exe.rsp   -mthreads -L.\..\..\lib\gcc_lib -Wl,--subsystem,windows -mwindows    -lwxmsw31u_core  -lwxbase31u    -lwxtiff -lwxjpeg -lwxpng   -lwxzlib -lwxregexu -lwxexpat   -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lwininet -loleacc -luxtheme
```

If we do the same command with `build=debug` instead we get similar commands with just a few differences:

```
windres --use-temp-file -i../../samples/sample.rc -ogcc_mswud\minimal_sample_rc.o    --define __WXMSW__       --define _UNICODE --include-dir .\..\..\lib\gcc_lib\mswud --include-dir ./../../include  --include-dir .  --include-dir ./../../samples --define NOPCH
g++ -c -o gcc_mswud\minimal_minimal.o -g -O0 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__       -D_UNICODE -I.\..\..\lib\gcc_lib\mswud -I.\..\..\include  -W -Wall -I.  -I.\..\..\samples -DNOPCH   -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy   -MTgcc_mswud\minimal_minimal.o -MFgcc_mswud\minimal_minimal.o.d -MD -MP minimal.cpp
g++ -o gcc_mswud\minimal.exe @gcc_mswud\minimal.exe.rsp  -g -mthreads -L.\..\..\lib\gcc_lib -Wl,--subsystem,windows -mwindows    -lwxmsw31ud_core  -lwxbase31ud    -lwxtiffd -lwxjpegd -lwxpngd   -lwxzlibd -lwxregexud -lwxexpatd   -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lwininet -loleacc -luxtheme
```

To build the sample with eclipse, we want to make it execute roughly the same commands accounting for the slight differences between the debug and release configuratins.  Select File->New->C/C++ project->C++ Managed Build. Enter a project name, select MinGW GCC, make sure the project type is Executable/Empty project, and click the finish button.

[image]

Now add a file to the project.  You can either

1. Selecting File->New->Source File, enter a name for the file such as "minimal.cpp" or whatever you want to call it, and hit finish.  The new file will automatically open in eclipse.  Select and delete the entire contents.  In a text editor, open the file WXWIN\samples\minimal\minimal.cpp, select and copy the entire contents, paste into the file just created in eclipse, and save the file.
2. File->Import->General->File System.  Click the next button.  Then select the \samples\minimal for the directory. Then select the file minimal.cpp from the list of files this brings up.  Finally hit the finish button.

Either way, there should now be a file named minimal.cpp in the project.  To build this file, several settings need to be changed.  From the menu, select Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings

- For GCC C++ Compiler:

  - For Preprocessor,

    - for all configurations add `__WXMSW__`, `_UNICODE`, `HAVE_W32API_H`, and `NOPCH`.
    - for the release configuration add `NDEBUG`
      [image]
  - For Includes

    - for all configurations, add `${WXWIN}\include`
    - for the debug configuration, add `${WXWIN}\lib\gcc_lib\mswud`
    - for the release configuration add `${WXWIN}\lib\gcc_lib\mswu`
  - For Optimization

    - for the release configuration select `Optimize more (-O2)`
  - For Debugging

    - for the debug configuration select Debug level `Default (-g)`
  - For Miscellaneous

    - for all configurations, add `-mthreads -W -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy` at the end of the "Other flags" box.
- For MinGW C++ Linker:

  - For Libraries,

    - for the debug configuration:

      - for Libraries, add 
        `wxmsw31ud_core`, `wxbase31ud`, `wxtiffd`, `wxjpegd`, `wxpngd`, `wxzlibd`, `wxregexud`, and `wxexpatd`
    - for the release configuration:

      - for Libraries, add all of the following: `wxmsw31u_core`, `wxbase31u`, `wxtiff`, `wxjpeg`, `wxpng`, `wxzlib`, `wxregexu`, and `wxexpat`
    - for all configurations

      - for Libraries, add all of the following: `kernel32`, `user32`, `gdi32`, `comdlg32`, `winspool`, `winmm`, `shell32`, `shlwapi`, `comctl32`, `ole32`, `oleaut32`, `uuid`, `rpcrt4`, `advapi32`, `version`, `wsock32`, `wininet`, `oleacc`, and `uxtheme`.
      - for Library search path, add `${WXWIN}\lib\gcc_lib`
    - **note**: with MinGW the order of libraries is sometimes important and the libraries with names starting with "wx" used with the debug and release configurations should be listed first.  You can use the up and down arrows to rearrange the order if necessary.
      [image]
  - For Miscelanious,

    - for all configurations

      - for liker flags, add `-mthreads -mwindows`
      - for Other options (-Xlinker), add `--subsystem=windows`.
    - for the debug configuration,

      - for liker flags, add `-g` to the existing contents.

Both the debug and release configurations will now build, but the application isn't complete quite yet.  The first thing done building the minimal application in the command prompt was

```
windres --use-temp-file ...
```

According to [this link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_to_handle_Resource-Script-Files_.27.2A.rc.27_with_CDT.3F), eclipse just doesn't support building resource files, so we need to handle this manually.

1. Copy the files WXWIN\samples\sample.rc and WXWIN\samples\sample.ico into the project folder. (The project folder is the folder containing the minimal.cpp file created earlier).  Alternately, you can use File->Import-> ... to import the files into the project.
2. Now go back Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Build Steps.

   - For Pre-build steps

     - for the debug configuration, enter `windres --use-temp-file -i"${ProjDirPath}/sample.rc" -o"${CWD}\minimal_sample_rc.o"    --define __WXMSW__ --define _UNICODE --include-dir ${WXWIN}\lib\gcc_lib\mswud --include-dir ${WXWIN}\include --define NOPCH`
     - for the release configuration enter `windres --use-temp-file -i"${ProjDirPath}\sample.rc" -o${CWD}\minimal_sample_rc.o    --define __WXMSW__ --define NDEBUG --define _UNICODE --include-dir ${WXWIN}\lib\gcc_lib\mswu --include-dir ${WXWIN}\include --define NOPCH`
       [image]
3. Next switch back to the Tool Settings tab:

   - For MinGW C++ Linker:

     - For Miscellaneous,

       - for all configurations

         - for Other objects, add `${CWD}\minimal_sample_rc.o`
           [image]

These 2 extra steps will make eclipse compile the resource file and link the resources into the final executable.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of instruction I need!  Thank you!  Sadly, Eclipse isn't cooperating-- everything I add to "debug" is applying to "all configurations" and everything I apply to "release" is forgotten.

Comment: I noticed that happening sometimes too.  I don't know if it's a bug or if I just don't really know how to use eclipse well. So some of these settings might take 2 tries to get right, but they did eventually take.

Comment: Successful compile and execution!

Comment: @CatherSteincamp, if you are on Windows you might want to install a free edition of MSVC - it is much easier to operate. And it is designed to work with C++ explicitly. Also, nothing beats MSVC debugger.

Answer (score 0):

So you start with a brand new project for C++.

Then you add the source code for minimal sample there.

Next you open the project properties you open "C++ Build" -> "Settings" and under "C++ Compiler"->"Directories", you add all your include directories.

Then you go to "C++ Linker"->"Libraries" and add the libraries and a path to them.

Let us know if you still have problems?

Comment: I have guessed at which TYPE of C++ Project as "C++ Managed Build".  Of all the guesses I had to make, this is the one I'm fairly confident of.  

I have guessed at what you mean by my include directories.  I came up with %WXDIR%\include, %WXDIR%\include\wx\

I have also guessed at what you mean by "the libraries"-- in the case, the 23 *.a files in %WXDIR%\lib\gcc_lib -- and the path (%WXDIR%\lib\)

Still have 37 "not resolved" and "invalid arguments" errors strewn throughout minimal.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful! Also works for the DLL version with library path `${WXWIN}\lib\gcc_dll` instead of `${WXWIN}\lib\gcc_lib` .

For a standalone executable, one might extract required DLLs from the vxWidgets library. A minimum post-build step for this is ...

DEBUG:

```
cmd.exe /Cfor %i in (wxmsw313ud_core wxbase313ud) do xcopy /D /Y "${WXWIN}\lib\gcc_dll\\%i_gcc_custom.dll"
```

RELEASE:

```
cmd.exe /Cfor %i in (wxmsw313u_core wxbase313u) do xcopy /D /Y "${WXWIN}\lib\gcc_dll\\%i_gcc_custom.dll"
```